# Azure .Net WebApp Deployment Failed but it works locally on VS

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am new to .Net and Unable to understand some weird behaviour with Azure.

I am trying to publish a .Net Project to Azure Web App. And It is throwing very silly errors. I assume thats becoz of new C# version.

Here is the log [file](http://txt.do/dorah).

Use Case 1: When trying to build from Visual Studio Team Services and then deploy using Continuous delivery Works.

Use Case 2: When trying to publish directly using Visual Studio using App Service profile and it works.

Use Case 3: When trying to deploy through repository that is hosted at Visual Studio Team Services. And it fails and thats the [error](http://txt.do/dorah).

Any lead will be helpful.

Do let me know, if the information provided is not enough.

Comment: when you say `Use Case 3: When trying to deploy through repository that is hosted at Visual Studio` what do you mean by that? how can visual studio host repository?

Answer (score 2):

To compile C# 7.0 code, we need msbuild 15 installed. Currently, msbuild15 is not enabled on Azure Web App.

For Use Case 1 and 2, the C#(7.0) code is build on your development side on which 
Visual Studio 2017(msbuild 15) is installed.

For Use Case 3, the code will be complied on Azure Web App, so it will throw errors.

Microsoft engineers are in the process of building these tools for Azure, they should be out soon. you could stay updated on [github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2350)

Comment: Any update? If you have further questions about this topic, please feel free to let me know. If my reply helps you find the root of your issue, please mark my reply as answer.